# PHP SoapClient call generates an ERR_NO_RESPONSE in browser and then a page reload

Tags: php, soap-client

I am using an external SOAP API (Interworx API - http://docs.interworx.com/interworx/api/index-Using-the-API.php#toc-Chapter-2) and when the SOAP call executes successfully I receive an 'ERR_NO_RESPONSE' or 'Unable to connect' or similar message in my browser (Chrome or Safari or Firefox).  When the SOAP command does not succeed, the page works fine and I receive the appropriate return array in $result.

The call is:

```
$client = new SoapClient($interworx_soap_url);
$result = $client->route($api_key, $api_controller, $action, $input);
```

The $client->route() command is creating a new domain pointer in my control panel.

Interestingly, the API call always works, but somehow it is interrupting my code execution.  I have tried adding an ob_start() and ob_clean() around these lines but it makes no difference.

So when my command $client->route() is successful (it creates a new domain pointer), it causes the problem (ERR_NO_RESPONSE in browser) but when the command is not successful (like when the domain pointer already exists) it works fine (returns the status array with the error message).

Any help solving or isolating the problem would be greatly appreciated.  Incidentally, this problem does not generate any messages in my PHP or server Apache error log.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try a successful call with SoapUI? Take a look if something wrong happens. After all, there's no sense to a call interfere the PHP output.

Comment: Yes, I am able to successfully perform a number of other commands, including listing the domain pointers.

Comment: There's any other code that you've omitted from here? Or, if don't, what's your PHP version, OS?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found my problem and it was not exactly a coding issue.  When I called the $client->route() command and a new pointer domain was created, the API also *restarted Apache* to make the new Server Alias live.  This was killing my script at exactly that point!  It turns out that there is a setting in Interworx that lets me force the restart to be "graceful" and this solved my problem.  The code was all good.  Thanks